# HttpClient fails to initialize

Tags: c#, httpclient

After running with the debugger this line of code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
```

the application suddenly exits. Anybody have some ideas why this appears?

This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => translate("en", "bg", "hello").Wait());
    }

static async Task translate(string sourceLang, string targetLang, string sourceText)
{
    string page = "http://www.transltr.org/api/translate?text=" + 
        sourceText + "&to=" + targetLang + "&from=" + sourceLang;

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string trans = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(trans);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

and it stops executing after this line

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of error message, perhaps printed to the debugging console? The docs don't mention any exceptions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138077(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Use a `try/catch` block and get the `Exception` details including type, message, stack trace, and inner exception details if there is one.

Comment: There is no error..i tried using try/ catch

Comment: what exit means?

Comment: it just finish executing code..but it is not executing all of the lines

Comment: You need to show us more code or some exception to further explain what is going on.

Comment: Since it is async, I doubt that you can catch it with a simple `catch` clause.

Comment: I'm guessing you have parallel tasks and you are not debugging correctly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155813.aspx

Comment: i only have one task

Comment: and it is the same result with or without the .Wait method

Comment: Just ran your code and got this output: `{"from":"en","to":"bg","text":"hello","translationText":"Здравейте"}`
So. It works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.Run(() => translate("en", "bg", "hello")).Wait();
```

Code is working, with a small adjustment you need to await task created at Task.Run